Where to throw away water hardness tests?
I was recently at a relative's house where we tested the hardness of the water. The testing kit contained two bottles A and B. Addition of one drop of A followed by addition of drops of B until colour change determined the hardness. One drop of each were required in 5 mL of water.
I didn't take a photo of the composition as it only provided the empirical formula of the various compounds, but it was complex (more than 6 molecules) and toxic to aquatic environments as symbolized by the pictogram below. There were no indications on what to do with the 5 mL of water after testing.

I was therefore wondering how to dispose of the solution. I have no idea whether A and B actually neutralize each other to produce something non-toxic to aquatic life, or at what concentrations they are actually toxic to aquatic life. Nevertheless, I assume it would probably be better if we didn't just throw random toxic chemicals down the sink or in our gardens.
I am therefore open to suggestions or opinions on how to deal with such a situation.
Note that I am aware you can buy strips, but the liquid testing kit was already present.
Thank you

Well, add the names of compounds, otherwise it's unclear.

As mentioned, only the empirical formulas were provided so I don't have the names of the compounds. I didn't have the chance to take a photo of the composition, but given that it was a complex mixture and that there was no way to derive the chemical structure from the empirical formula I don't think it is that relevant for my issue.

Well, identifying the method should be easy enough. It could for ex. use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murexide

For the total hardness, there is probably ammonia pH buffer, EDTA and Eriochrome Black T as complexometric indicator. The former two are harmless enough when diluted by water and the indicator is already very diluted when used, not speaking about dilution at disposal.
Similarly a diluted acid with pH indicator (probably methyl orange) for the carbonate/temporary hardness. Dilution at water sink disposal is enough.
I remember some aquarium test kit involving exactly this.
Most of home cleaners are more nasty than these two sets.
